# Phrase that means: "it's very [someone] style"?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

Example sentence:

> She suggested we go to an underground rock bar. That __ her.

I few options I can think of: "... very becoming of her" and "... was very her."

Are these valid options? Or there's a better one?

(I'm looking for something colloquial.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really understand what "becoming of her" means here, but to me it sounds closer to she was acting appropriately, or correctly. This is not what you intend.

*It was very her* could possibly work in a very colloquial way, non-standard way. Similarly, *that was very her of her* is also possible. But I think the more common way is with *so*. I wasn't sure of the best definition for this usage, but this one seems to fit:

> [so](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so)
>   not standard used before a noun or before "not" to emphasize what is being said:
>   *Don't wear that - it's so last year (= it was fashionable last year but not now).*
>   *I'm sorry, but she is so not a size 10 (= she is very much larger than a size 10).*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

It's colloquial. It's way to emphasize that the action is a characteristic or style of the person in your case.

*Example:*

> She suggested we go to an underground rock bar. That's **so** her.

*Possible variation:*

> That's so like her.

Answer (score 1):

"Very becoming of her" doesn't sound like a very "valid" choice here, rather than that a possible choice could be:

> how fitting of her

which would go

> She suggested we go to an underground rock bar. how fitting of her.

if "That" is needed it could also go

> She suggested we go to an underground rock bar. That's very fitting of her.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the name of the person you're speaking of:

> That's very Alice.
>
> That's so Alice.

or a pronoun:

> That's so (like) her.

or just

> That's Alice.

The meaning is that what you have just mentioned is a quintessential example of Alice, typical of the sort of things she says or does.